# doing math with ruby

Tags: ruby, math, shoes

I'm refactgoring a learning game for kids to learn spelling and math. I'm trying to expand the math by multiplication, subtraction and division operators.

The problem occurs when the process loopes for a long time, because I don't want it to return a negative number.

Brief process description:
The two numbers for selected operator are generated randomly from ranges (currently 0..9). The computation executes and if the result is a negative number the whole process runs again.

The problem of course occurs only with subtraction and division.

Sources:

- loop code: lines 82 to 85 in https://github.com/sebastjan-hribar/abc123/blob/master/lib/abc123.rb
- helpers: https://github.com/sebastjan-hribar/abc123/blob/master/lib/abc123/helpers_math.rb

My question?

Is there a more elegant way of implementing these calculations to avoid the result often being a negative number (maybe by predefining the numbers to be used as input1 and input2)?

The addition runs ok, but with subtraction it often loops w/o end.

Comment: pick number *a* from 0..9 and number *b* from 0..a

Comment: While this may be answered here, questions like `is my implementation good?` or `how can I improve this code?` are better for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange

Comment: Don't link to your code; most people won't follow the link.  Post it here instead.  Subtraction results in a negative number 45% of the time.  Unless you have a really slow loop, that should be sufficient.

Comment: @Stefan is exactly right. You only need to do that for subtraction though.

Comment: Thank you all!
I'll keep in  mind the code linking and code review suggestions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of while and stuff you should do something like this:

```
  def compute(operator)
    input_1, input_2 = prepare_arguments(operator)
    result = case operator
    when "add"
      input_1 + input_2
    when "multiply"
      input_1 * input_2
    when "subtract"
      input_1 - input_2
    when "divide"
      input_1 / input_2
    end

    {result: result, operator: operator, input_1: input_1, input_2: input_2}
  end

  def prepare_arguments(operator)
    case operator
    when "subtract"
      [first_argument = rand(0..9), first_argument + rand(0..9)].reverse
    when "divide"
      [first_argument = rand(1..9), first_argument * rand(0..9)].reverse
    else
      [rand(0..9), rand(0..9)]
    end
  end
```

So if you have an operator it will result with correct arguments and the result of computation.

Comment: Thank you for this solution!